# SQLLDR file path argument

Tags: oracle, loading, sql-loader

I have more than 30 files to load the data.
The path changes at every run in those files. So the path becomes

```
INFILE "/home/dmf/Cycle7Data/ITEM_IMAGE.csv"
INFILE "/home/dmf/Cycle8Data/ITEM_IMAGE.csv"
```

The file names change on every control file (SUPPLIER.csv)

Is there any way to pass the File path in a variable, or set any Env. Variable?
So that the control file is not edited everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data file name on the command line; [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_params.htm#SUTIL1023):

> DATA specifies the name of the data file containing the data to be loaded. If you do not specify a file extension or file type, then the default is .dat.
>
> If you specify a data file on the command line and also specify data files in the control file with INFILE, then the data specified on the command line is processed first. The first data file specified in the control file is ignored. All other data files specified in the control file are processed.

So pass the relevant file name with each invocation, e.g.

```
sqlldr user/passwd control=myfile.ctl data=/home/dmf/Cycle7Data/ITEM_IMAGE.csv
```

If you have lots of files to load from a directory you could have a shell script that loops over the directory contents and passes each file name in turn to an SQL*Loader session.